# Linux bash: find full path of target file when executed via a softlink

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

How can I find full path of the original file being executed when user executes file not directly but through a softlink. To be more precise, assume I have `/original/path/a.sh`, and a softlink to that file here: `~/Desktop/link-to-a.sh`. How can I find `"/original/path/"` inside `a.sh` if user actually executes `~/Desktop/link-to-a.sh`?

The following variable holds ~/Desktop/ which is not useful.

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
```

Comment: You might find [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) useful. Note that "soft links" may also be referred to as "symlinks" or "symbolic links".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `readlink`.

To get the real path to a soft linked directory containing your script :

```
DIR=`dirname $0`
DIR=`readlink -f $DIR`
```

If your soft link points directly to the script, not its directory, do this to get the real directory in which the script is contained :

```
FILE=`readlink -f $0`
DIR=`dirname $FILE`
```

Comment: Are u sure it works? readlink accepts file (softlink) not its parent directory. `dirname` returns parent directory, not full path to the link.

Comment: You mean you have a soft link directly to the file, not its directory ? If so the new solution may be the one you want.

Comment: My softlink points to the file, but I want original directory of that file. Your last edit returns original bash file. Is it possible to get only directory part of that?